# Compiled with problems:X ERROR in ./src/components/Header.js 9:0-52 Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@mui/icons-material/Search

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, material-icons

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@mui/icons-material/Search' in 'C:\Users\pande\Documents\slack-clone\src\components'

Failed to compile.

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@mui/icons-material/Search' in 'C:\Users\pande\Documents\slack-clone\src\components'
ERROR in ./src/components/Header.js 9:0-52
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@mui/icons-material/Search' in 'C:\Users\pande\Documents\slack-clone\src\components'

webpack compiled with 1 error

Header.js file

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import { Avatar } from "@mui/material";
import SearchIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Search';
import AccessTimeIcon from "@mui/icons-material/AccessTime";
import HelpOutlineIcon from "@mui/icons-material/HelpOutline";
import { useAuthState } from "react-firebase-hooks/auth";
import { auth } from "../Firebase";


    function Header () {
    const [user] = useAuthState(auth);

    return (
        <HeaderContainer>
            {/* header left */}
        <HeaderLeft>
            <HeaderAvatar
            onClick={() => auth.signOut()}
            alt={user?.displayName}
            src={user?.photoURL}
            />
            <AccessTimeIcon />
        </HeaderLeft>
            
        <HeaderSearch>
                <SearchIcon/>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search" />
        </HeaderSearch>
        <HeaderRight>
            <HelpOutlineIcon />
        </HeaderRight>
        </HeaderContainer>
    );
    };

    export default Header;

    const HeaderSearch = styled.div`
    flex: 0.4;
    opacity: 1;
    border-radius: 6px;
    background-color: #421f44;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    padding: 0 50px;
    color: gray;
    border: 1px gray solid;

    > input {
        background-color: transparent;
        border: none;
        text-align: center;
        min-width: 30vw;
        outline: 0;
        color: white;
    }
    `;

    const HeaderContainer = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 10px 0;
    background-color: var(--slack-color);
    color: white;
    `;

    const HeaderLeft = styled.div`
    flex: 0.3;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-left: 20px;
    > .MuiSvgIcon-root {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: 30px;
    }
    `;

    const HeaderRight = styled.div`
    flex: 0.3;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    > .MuiSvgIcon-root {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: 30px;
    }
    `;

    const HeaderAvatar = styled(Avatar)`
    cursor: pointer;

    :hover {
        opacity: 0.8;
    }
`;

package.json file


{
  "name": "slack-clone",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.8.4",
    "@mui/material": "^5.9.3",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.3.0",
    "firebase": "^9.9.1",
    "firebase-hooks": "^0.0.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-firebase-hooks": "^5.0.3",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-spinkit": "^3.0.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "styled-components": "^5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react-spinkit": "^3.0.7",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.25"
  }
}
```

Comment: `import { SearchIcon, AccessTimeIcon,AccessTimeIcon,Avatar } from '@mui/icons-material';`
try using this way maybe it will work

Comment: The above mentioned question link has been asked by me only and that is not working that is why i am asking again. The suggested code by you is not working as well.

Comment: only the  SearchIcon getting this error ? . another working fine or what?

Comment: `<IconButton color="inherit">
            <SearchIcon />
          </IconButton>`  try to put it in a iconButton tag

Comment: This is the error with the search icon only other icons are successfully imported and working. I tried putting in iconButton tag but the same error has occurred.

Comment: maybe you need to add textfield  `<TextField
  label="With normal TextField"
  InputProps={{
    endAdornment: (
      <InputAdornment>
        <IconButton>
          <SearchIcon />
        </IconButton>
      </InputAdornment>
    )
  }}
/>` try this way

Comment: Error is still there with searchIcon. Is there not any other way to represent it?

Comment: It seems like you are confused using Material-ui v5 and v4. You installed v4 icons and tried to import v5 icons

Comment: Check my package.json file I have installed v5 icons only.